# Failed to configure ILM

Tags: fim

> UserProfileApplication.SynchronizeMIIS: Failed to configure ILM, will
>   attempt during next rerun. Exception: System.FormatException: Index
>   (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the
>   size of the argument list.      at
>   System.Text.StringBuilder.AppendFormatHelper(IFormatProvider provider,
>   String format, ParamsArray args)      at
>   System.String.FormatHelper(IFormatProvider provider, String format,
>   ParamsArray args)      at System.String.Format(IFormatProvider
>   provider, String format, Object[] args)      at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.ProfileSynchronizationServiceInstance.IsStarted(ServiceController
>   controller)      at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.ProfileSynchronizationServiceInstance.WaitUntilStarted()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplication.SetupSynchronizationService(ProfileSynchronizationServiceInstance
>   profileSyncInstance).

---

I've tried changing the registry for FIM, DependOnService but that suggestion didnt work out for me.

Any ideas?

Comment: did you see any dependency? right click on the FIM service and under dependenc tab see if their is any listed?

Comment: also login with Farm admin acocunt on the SYnc server and make sure following url will be accessable...crl.microsoft.com
ctldl.windowsupdate.com
ctldl.windowsupdate.nsatc.net
www.update.microsoft.com.nsatc.net

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE what if the server do not have Internet access? Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 1):

I got it fixed.

When starting the UPAS the FIM tried to check the firewall ports.
I looked inside my Windows Firewall and saw that the service had created 25-30 firewall rules.
ILM Web Service - RMS and the ILM Web Service -STS.

I deleted all the rules and started the User Profile Sync, the FIM created two new rules and the the service started.

I dont know who to mark this question as answerd but here it goes :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you removed the key from the registry rather than modifying it? Try removing the key completely and provisioning again.

Also, does the farm account have internet access from the server? If not, can this be provided for the startup of the service?

Obviously it's worth exporting that portion of the registry before removing the key just in case you decide you need it later!

Andy

Comment: I have tried removing it, I have tried editing it.

The farm account got internet access. I can access Google and Microsofts site.